# Function fetch() failed

Tags: javascript

I would like to ask you about download file with vertex position for webgl.
I tried to use fetch() function with URL https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/models/cube/cube.obj and it works fine. After that I saved the file and start server on http://localhost:4000/cube.obj and the function fetch() always stops and fail without error description. I haven't tried to set up some options, because I am little bit confused.

```
async function main() {
    const response = await fetch('https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/models/cube/cube.obj');
    if (!response.ok) {
      alert("err");
    }
    else
    {
      alert("ok");
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Could you help me with this problem, please?

Comment: You probably can't `fetch()` that file from another site. Use `/cube.obj` if your app is on `http://localhost:4000/` and `cube.obj` is available as `http://localhost:4000/cube.obj`...

Comment: "without error description — This seems unlikely. Do you know how to use the developer tools console to see any error messages?

Comment: my app is on http://localhost:3333 and try to connect server http://localhost:4000, it is interesting that  https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/models/cube/cube.obj works fine...

Answer (score 0):

There is a Response that is returned. You want to look at `Response.status` and `Response.statusText` for information about what happened.

```
const myImage = document.querySelector('img');

const myRequest = new Request('flowers.jpg');

fetch(myRequest).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.statusText); // returns "OK" if the response returned successfully
  response.blob().then((myBlob) => {
    const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
    myImage.src = objectURL;
  });
});
```

Comment: it is interesting that nothing response.statusText is returned... the script abort during fetch()...